# scrollTop not working when page scrolled half way down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I am developing app for Iphone and I have a problem. I am using to `scrollTop()` to navigate to top of the page when side panel is opened. If the page is scrolled down as much as the side panel can bee seen a little bit it wont scroll to the top, but when I can not see the panel it will scroll to top.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" align="center">
    <div data-role="panel" id="popupPanel" data-position="left" ontouchmove="event.preventDefault()" data-display="reveal">
        <h3 id="userName2" class="blockText2"></h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <a data-icon="false" data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="b" id="seeYourProfile" href="#yourProfile" data-transition="slide" class="contentLink">Profile</a>
            <a data-icon='false' data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="b" href="#about" class="contentLink">About</a>
            <a data-icon='false' data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="b" href="#contacts" class="contentLink">My Contacts</a>
            <a data-icon='false' data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="b" href="#teams" class="contentLink">My Teams</a>
            <a data-icon='false' data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="b" onclick="sc.signOut();return false;" class="contentLink">Logout</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" style="z-index:99999;">
        <a href="#home" data-theme="none" data-role="none" id="btPopUpPanel" style="float:left;color:lightgrey;text-decoration:none;" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide"><i class="icon-reorder icon-2x"></i></a>
        <h1>News feed</h1>
        <a data-role="none" data-theme="none" id="btRefreshAllActivities" style="float:left;color:lightgrey;text-decoration:none;" data-transition="slide"><i class="icon-refresh icon-2x"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <h3 id="noActivities">No activities found.</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" id="listActivities"></ul>
        <div id="submitBtn" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <button type="submit" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="btMoreActivity">More Activity</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$('#btPopUpPanel').on('vclick', function() {
    if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
        $("#popupPanel").panel("open");
        $("#popupPanel").scrollTop();
    } else {
        $("#popupPanel").panel("close");
    }
});
```

I have also tried `$("#home").scrollTop();` and `$("#popupPanel").scrollTo(0,0);` but it didn't work. Anyone has some suggestions?

Comment: Still struggling with this issue. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer myself instead of using `$("#popupPanel").scrollTop();` I used `document.getElementById('popupPanel').scrollIntoView();`

Answer (score 0):

instant scroll to top

```
 $(document).scrollTop(0);
```

animated scroll 300 ms

```
$('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
}, 300);
```